# Having persistent and non persistent objects of the same type with CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

I am currently working on an iPhone app which uses CoreData to save some Objects persistently.

To make my point clear I want to give you a short introduction into the scenario:

I have some Data which I query from the Internet. I save this data in an object called MyData and use it where I need it. When the data is used I want to save it persistently so I save it to a MyManagedData object.

I really don't like this solution for saving data. Because I have two classes saving exactly the same data, but one is managed by CoreData.

Is there a way to instantiate managed objects without saving them automatically to CoreData? So I can just have MyManagedData objects and save just a bunch of them? How do you construct such things?

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One viable approach is to have two managed object contexts. You're already using a context for your main persisted data, so you could create a new context for your 'scratch' data which you never save.

There's a few articles out there on the subject, such as http://www.timisted.net/blog/archive/multiple-managed-object-contexts-with-core-data/.

I've been using [InnerBand](http://raptureinvenice.com/innerband-2/) to help with CoreData. It's simplified my code quite a bit and not got in the way.

If you use InnerBand, creating a temporary context/store for storing transient entities (not saved) should just be a case of doing the following:

```
// note - not calling [CoreDataStore mainStore] here --
// we use that for persisted main data
self.temporaryStore = [CoreDataStore createStore]; 

// and then create temporary entities like so:
MyEntityClass *myEntity = [MyEntity createInStore:self.temporaryStore];
```

Obviously, you should never call `[self.temporaryStore save]`, as it is for transient data only.

Note: I've not tried the above strategy myself yet, but I believe it to be workable.

N.B. on a related issue, I'm also using [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) which takes the pain out of generating entity classes (and prevents clobbering of custom code you may have added to your entities classes when you regenerate the entity classes).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is delete the managed objects you no longer want before you save the context. That way the context will only write the objects you want to retain to the persistent store.

However, I wouldn't bother. I would just tell the context to delete objects when they are no longer needed and not to worry about whether they were written to disk at any particular time or not. If you've got so little data that you can keep it all in memory at once then the overhead of writing those objects to disk just to delete them later will be trivial.

Comment: Thx. But having a NSMangedObject for every object which will perhabs saved sometimes involves much boiler plate code I really dont want to deal with, if I dont have to.

Comment: Not when compared with the overhead of tracking two different sets of objects, some saved and some not. Based on your names and your description of the use of Core Data, I don't think you are using it properly. I think you are wasting time and effort in a misguided attempt to save time and effort.

Comment: Thats maybe a good point. I have some classes for objects in my system which I pass from object to object as parameter or return value. I have to create this objects use them and release them in some case, in the other case I need this objects (or the data they contain) and save them. 
The best way might be to have a container for this objects data to save them? Or is this a wrong use?
If I would write myself a SQLite wrapper myself I would implement a loader class which gives me the data of some database entry in such an object.

Comment: I think you believe that Core Data has a lot of overhead when it does not. It is very lightweight and optimized to the point is nearly impossible to do better with custom code or SQL, except for some limited cases. E.g. I use Core Data for things I used to used arrays and dictionaries for. It's just easier to have everything managed for you. Of course, this is because I thoroughly understand Core Data. If you have enough data that you are contemplating using SQL, then you should just use Core Data IF you have enough time to learn it. If not, then go with what you know now and upgrade later.